# The volume of a 3N-dimensional hypershell

Tags: calculus, volume

R.K. Pathria in his book *Statistical Mechanics* has written that the volume of a $3N$-dimensional hypershell, bounded by hyper spheres of radii $$\sqrt{2m(E+\tfrac12\Delta)}\; \text{and}\; \sqrt{2m(E-\tfrac12\Delta)}$$ for $\Delta\ll E$, is almost equal to $\Delta (m/2E)^{\frac12}$ multiplied by the surface area of a $3N$-dimensional hypersphere of radius $\sqrt{2mE}$. Could you explain to me why?

Comment: In the third edition, this is in Sec. 2.4. I've corrected your use of braces without preceding backslashes, which in LaTeX/MathJax makes them invisible. The original uses round brackets anyway. This makes clear $\Delta$ has the same units as $E$, not $mE$. Hint: the shell's "volume" (a $3N$-measure) is approximately its "area" (a $3N-1$-measure) multiplied by its thickness, which can be approximated with$$\sqrt{a+b}-\sqrt{a-b}=\frac{2b}{\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{a-b}}\sim\frac{b}{\sqrt{a}}$$for $b\ll a$.

Comment: @J.G. Got it perfectly. Thank you very much for your explanations and yout help. Appreciate that.